# PHP CodeIgniter one database per user

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to use CodeIgniter and DBForge to create a multi tenant app. I'll have my central database with a 'users' table that will store the name of the user and the name of their database.

The problem I'm having is creating the individual databases and their tables. Here's a snippet of the code:

```
if ($this->dbforge->create_database( $db_name ))
    {

            echo 'Database created!';

            // an array of fields
            $fields = array(
                    'name' => array(
                            'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                            'constraint' => '100',
                    ),
            );

            // set them up for the new table
            $this->dbforge->add_field($fields);

            // create the new table in the new db
            $this->dbforge->create_table('items');

    }
```

The database $db_name is created without any problems but when I create the table 'items', it's created on my central database which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi when you are trying to create table it is creating table in your default connected database, you have to reconnect your database with user created database and pass that connected database object to $this->db and reforage again than it will create table in user database here how you can create table in user database

```
if ($this->dbforge->create_database($db_name)) {

            echo 'Database created!';
            // an array of fields

            $config['hostname'] = "localhost";
            $config['username'] = "root";
            $config['password'] = "";
            $config['database'] = $db_name;
            $config['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
            $config['dbprefix'] = "";
            $config['pconnect'] = FALSE;
            $config['db_debug'] = TRUE;
            $config['cache_on'] = FALSE;
            $config['cachedir'] = "";
            $config['char_set'] = "utf8";
            $config['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";

            $this->db = $this->load->database($config, TRUE); //<- magic start from here 

            $this->load->dbforge();

            $fields = array(
                'name' => array(
                    'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                    'constraint' => '100',
                ),
            );

            // set them up for the new table
            $this->dbforge->add_field($fields);

            // create the new table in the new db
            $this->dbforge->create_table('items');
        }
```

to make your code more clean create one user_db.php file in application/config and put user config there and every time $config['database'] in your code

Comment: Thank you umefarooq - that's perfect and is doing exactly what I need!